# Old WhatsApp version is obsolete on January 2018, but there's no update on the Play Store

Tags: updates, whatsapp-messenger

WhatsApp shows a notice that the current version is old and obsolete, preventing the user from accessing the chats. It also tells the user to download the latest update.

[image]

Tapping the "download" button takes the user to the Play Store. However, there is no option to "update", only "uninstall" and "open".

[image]

How to force update the WhatsApp app?

Answer (score 1):

Download the APK file directly from [the official WhatsApp site](https://www.whatsapp.com/android/) and install it.

I have the same issue and this fixed it.